# Setting the user agent works for one site but fails for another

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver, user-agent, geckodriver

Setting the user agent in python for Geckodriver (v. 0.18) with Selenium (3.4.3) works for one site but fails for another.

```
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
#self.base_url = "http://whatsmyuseragent.com/"
self.base_url = "http://www.google.com"
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
firefox_profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\Drivers\geckodriver', firefox_profile=firefox_profile) 

self.driver.get(self.base_url)  

agent =  self.driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
print(agent)
```

The error message from the google site is:

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
```